# Johnny five and multiple boards - how to recognize which board I am connected to

Tags: javascript, arduino, johnny-five

Let's say I am connecting 2 Arduino boards to the computer and I want to use Johnny-five here. Each of boards is used to different tasks, for example one reads sensors, the other controls some LEDs. So it is important to me to read/write signals to appropriate boards.

**I am looking for some flexibility here, because I found out that:**

Here I don't know which board got key A and which B, and I can't guarantee that keys will not be opposite when I connect my arduinos to another machine:

```
new five.Boards([ "A", "B" ]);
```

Here I know exactly which board is connected to which port, but I can't hardcode it if I am planning to connect boards to another machine:

```
new five.Boards([ "/dev/cu.usbmodem621", "/dev/cu.usbmodem411" ]);
```

The only idea I have for now is to use a kind of jumpers, by wiring for example pin10 to +5V on board 1, and to the ground on board 2, or even use resistors and have many signal levels (if I plan to connect more boards), then probe the pin and just get info which board I am connected to and assign it to A or B in the array. After that I would run the main code with my program.

**My question is:** Do you see any other approach giving you guarantee that you "talk" to correct board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1: Use dip switch to set device ID

use a  2 or 4 switch dip switch to identify the board.  Each switch could go to an individual Digital input.

The more switches, the more boards you can have

- 1 bit - 2 boards
- 2 bit - 4 boards
- 4 bit - 16 boards
- 8 bit - 256 boards

In a 2 bit configuration,

- 00 - Board A
- 01 - Board B
- 10 - Board C
- 11 - Board D

### Option 2: Modify Firmata and hardcode a device ID

Extend and customize firmata firmware.  I've determined that this isn't a very good option.

### Option 3: Use filename/firmware name

I got a lot of good advice on this from the Johnny-Five & Frimata groups.  Johnny Five uses the file name for the firmware name, which can be accessed by the board object in Johnny-Five.

`firmware: { version: [Object], name: 'AdvancedFirmata.ino' },`

In my case, I just renamed the filename when I compile the AdvancedFirmata code and upload it to the device.

`firmware: { version: [Object], name: 'boardA.ino' },`

This is what I'm going to use in my project to identify different boards through `board.io.firmware.name`

This seems to be the best solution.

Update: Here is a complete example.  In my case, I made things a lot more configurable, but this will work:

```
var boards = new five.Boards("A","B");
var j5 = {}
boards.on("ready", function(){
  this.each(function(board){

    // Set up LED on board B
    if(board.io.firmware.name == "BoardA.ino"){
      j5.ledA = new five.Led({
        pin: 13,
        board: board
      });
    }

    // Set up LED on board B
    else if (board.io.firmware.name == "BoardB.ino"){
      j5.ledB = new five.Led({
        pin: 13,
        board: board
      });
    }


  });
});
```

Now you can do:

```
// Toggle LED A every 500ms
setInterval(function(){
  j5.ledA.toggle();
},500); 

// Toggle LED B every 250ms
setInterval(function(){
  j5.ledB.toggle();
},250);
```